# Closing Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Recently I had to edit my program code so that the form will close after creating a PDF. In `FormClosing()` there's a `MessageBox.Show` for closing or not, depending on the `DialogResult`. The problem is that when I try to `Close()`, it shows me the `MessageBox`, I need to close it without showing it. Thanks.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void btn_PdfCreate_CloseForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showPDf();
    // close pdf but skip MessageBox
}
```

Comment: You anyways want to close the form after pdf creation. So, there is no need of that msgbox at all here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop listening to the event like so

```
private void btn_PdfCreate_CloseForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormClosing -= Form1_FormClosing
    showPDf();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: downvoted for irrelevance: How is that answering the question?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: The OP seems to think it did... ;)

Comment: Everyone has the right to be wrong... so do I.
However, I still think that using e.ClosingReason is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CloseReason` property of the `FormClosingEventArgs`:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClosingReason == CloseReason.UserClosing && MessageBox.Show("Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use e.ClosingReason to find out if the formClosing event was fired by the user's attempt to close the form, or by something else.

for further reading, go to MSDN:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You anyways want to close the form after pdf creation. So call Form's `Dispose` method just after pdf creation like below and no need of registering for the `OnFormClosing` event

```
private void btn_PdfCreate_CloseForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showPDf();
    this.Dispose();
}
```